# Too slow when sum and group data around 100,000 records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently, I'm using the SQL Server 2008 R2. My table has around 100,000 records with these columns: ColA, ColB, Weight, Volume, Quantity.

Here is my query string:

```
select ColA, ColB, sum(([Weight]/Volume)*Quantity) as 'Result'
from dbo.TblSample
group by ColA, ColB
```

It took so long to finish (more than 10 minutes).

Could someone help me to improve this query?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `ColA` and `ColB`?

Comment: hi shree, I dont use index for these two columns. Please advise.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX IX_NAME ON tblSample (ColA, ColB) INCLUDE (Weight, Volume, Quantity)` but *100,000 records ... It took so long to finish (more than 10 minutes).* makes it seem like you've got some other problem. SQL Server should be able to clustered index scan 100k rows in your average table in little time. Update stats and check the execution plan. Or maybe you have huge rows?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information provided, I would suggest that you create an index on the columns `ColA` and `ColB`. The idea is that you get a performance improvement when the columns used for grouping or filtering are indexed.

For a detailed example, you can check out [this article](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/articles/sql-server-bi/49/indexing-for-aggregates-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thank Shree. I'll apply as your advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(result),ColA, ColB FROM 
(
select ColA, ColB, ([Weight]/Volume)*Quantity as 'Result'
from dbo.TblSample
) tmp

group by ColA, ColB
```

OR USE COMMON TABLE EXPRESSIONS

```
WITH CTE 
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
   select ColA, ColB, ([Weight]/Volume)*Quantity as 'Result' 
from dbo.TblSample
)

SELECT SUM(result),ColA, ColB FROM CTE group by ColA, ColB
```

Comment: Thank Timus, but it still run very slow.